# iPhone app Custom UIWindow wrong frame in iPad Landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, landscape, uiwindow

I am writing an iPhone app using custom UIWindow.(xCode6.1, iOS8.1)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width)];
    [_window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It targets iPhone, Landscape only. All works fine on all iPhone devices, but when it runs on iPad, the UIWindow frame is broken.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Why did you change the width and height (and not use the origin of the screen bounds)?

Comment: @David, AFAIK, UIWindow coordinate is always portrait based, and current code works fine in all iPhone devices.